# UIDeviceOrientation issue with iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an iPad in which I start at a landscape left orientation, however when I do:

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

it doesn't detect it as landscape left. I had to rotate it to portrait mode and then back to landscape left again, and then when I check the orientation, now it's correct. However, initially when it's launched it is not correct. Why is this? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, are you asking why `orientation` is not returning what you expect or why the app is not rotating as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use the *Device* Orientation if you would like to determine the *Interface* Orientation!

If you have a reference to the RootViewController of your main window, you could ask it for its `interfaceOrientation`.
If you don't, use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` to determine the Interface Orientation.